# Find The Row on Label Caption

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, label, caption

I have a UserForm with a label ID. I need to find and modify the row only if the first column of the row is equal to the label Id caption of the form.

When I press the button nothing happens to the selected row.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim I as integer 
    For I = 2 to Worksheets(“sheet1”).Range(“A10000”).end(xlUp).row
        If cells (i, 1) = label1.caption then
            Cells (i, 3).Value  = TextBox1.text
        End if
    Next I
End sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have add some explanation

Comment: If the command button is on the worksheet, you should use something like 'UserForm1.Label1.Caption' and 'UserForm1.TextBox1.Text' or if the command button  is on the user form but the text box is on the worksheet, then you have to use 'Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Text' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? Assume the button is on a form with the label and textbox?

If it only occurs once then could exit the loop once found.

I've added some sheet references and changed the curly quotes for straight ones.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim I as long

For I = 2 to Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A10000").end(xlUp).row
   If Worksheets("sheet1").cells(i, 1) = label1.caption then
       Worksheets("sheet1").Cells (i, 3).Value  = TextBox1.text
   End if
Next I 

End sub
```